# OpenSSL SSL_connect SYSCALL error with Netty tcnative

Tags: java, c++, openssl, netty, tls1.2

I am connecting to a Java (netty-tcnative) server using Berkeley sockets and OpenSSL 1.1.1k on Windows using C++. Sometimes during the connection phase, I'll receive a `SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL` from `SSL_connect`. If I attempt to get more information from this SYSCALL error (per OpenSSL documentation) using `ERR_get_error` I get a return value of 0. The state of the TLS connection is `SSLv3/TLS write client hello`. After some testing on my end, I found the issue is only reproduced when I reconnect the socket (possible TLS session resumption?)

3 questions here:

- Is there a flag or boolean I can set to enable debug logging on OpenSSL side or a way for me to verify my suspicions that OpenSSL is attempting to resume the TLS session?
- Is there a flag for me to set on Netty tcnative side to log the TLS handshake similar to `-Djavax.net.debug=all`?
- Is this a client-sided issue or server-sided issue?

I am using version 2.0.40 of netty-tcnative on Debian 10.

My C++ client-side code is running on MSVC 2017 and Windows 10.

C++ code for creating `SSL_ctx`:

```cpp
auto ssl_ctx = SSL_CTX_new(TLS_client_method());
SSL_CTX_set_max_proto_version(ssl_ctx, TLS1_3_VERSION); // Use TLS 1.3 if possible
SSL_CTX_set_min_proto_version(ssl_ctx, TLS1_2_VERSION); // Use TLS 1.2 at a minimum
```

C++ code for client-side connection:

```cpp
const int sslErr = SSL_connect(ssl);
if (sslErr <= 0) {
    const int sslErrCode = SSL_get_error(ssl, sslErr);
    if (sslErrorCode == SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL) {
        const unsigned long errGetErr = ERR_get_error();
        //const OSSL_HANDSHAKE_STATE state = SSL_get_state(ssl);
        const char* stateStr = SSL_state_string_long(ssl);
        std::cout << "SSL_connect error: " << sslErrCode << std::endl;
        std::cout << "ERR_get_error error: " << errGetErr << std::endl;
        std::cout << "state: " << stateStr << std::endl;
        if (sslErrCode == SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL) {
            char buffer[256] = { 0 };
            ERR_error_string_n(errGetErr, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
            printf_s(buffer);
            printf_s("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Output from the program:

```
SSL_connect error: 5
ERR_get_error error: 0
state: SSLv3/TLS write client hello
error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0)
```

Code on server-side (netty pipeline):

```java
@Override
protected final void initChannel(Channel ch) throws Exception {
    ChannelPipeline pipe = ch.pipeline();
    SslContext sslCtx = SslContextBuilder.forServer(keyCertChainFile, keyFile).sslProvider(SslProvider.OPENSSL).build();
    pipe.addLast("ssl", sslCtx.newHandler(ch.alloc()));
}
```

Comment: This might be due the fact that netty doesn't allow renegotiation. Did you see any error logged on the server side?

Comment: I do not see any errors, however after turning on debug logging in `io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSsl` I found I am using `BoringSSL` instead of the intended `OpenSSL` as well as `Supported protocols (OpenSSL): [SSLv2Hello, TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3]` This may have been the reason for the handshake problem since the client will reject anything under TLS 1.2, I will look into this further and follow up. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of debugging I finally have an answer to this question.

- Is there a flag or boolean I can set to enable debug logging on OpenSSL side or a way for me to verify my suspicions that OpenSSL is attempting to resume the TLS session?

If you are using BoringSSL and not the Netty-tcnative OpenSSL dynamic library, TLS renegotiation is **not** supported. In fact, BoringSSL does not support TLS renegotiation at all. It is mentioned in their documentation [here](https://boringssl.googlesource.com/boringssl/+/HEAD/PORTING.md#tls-renegotiation)

- Is there a flag for me to set on Netty tcnative side to log the TLS handshake similar to -Djavax.net.debug=all?

For the reader reading this, if you happen to run into this issue I would highly suggest making sure you are logging all TLS handshake errors in your server handler. Reference the following code segment as this will alert you to the handshake errors as they occur.

```
@Override
public final void userEventTriggered(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object evt) throws Exception {
    if (evt instanceof SslHandshakeCompletionEvent) {
        SslHandshakeCompletionEvent hsEvt = (SslHandshakeCompletionEvent) evt;
        if (hsEvt.isSuccess()) {
            // handshake success
        } else {
            Throwable cause = hsEvt.cause();
            LOGGER.error("SSL Handshake Failure: {}", cause.getLocalizedMessage(), cause);
        }
    }
}
```

- Is this a client-sided issue or server-sided issue?

For me personally, this was a client-sided issue. After digging through the OpenSSL documentation for version 1.1.1l, there is a quick [side-note](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/SSL_get_error.html#BUGS) that states when a `SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL` occurs with an errno of 0 (fetched using `ERR_get_error`) indicates an EOF from the peer. From this note, you should see who is closing the connection and check the state of the socket. Since I am using winsock, the error I got is `WSAENOTCONN` meaning the connection was not valid when I attempted `SSL_connect`. `SSL_connect` under the hood performs socket writes/reads as it performs the TLS handshake here. If any socket writes/reads occur while the socket is not connected, `WSAGetLastError` will return `WSAENOTCONN`. I did not see any logs indicating a closed connection on the Netty side so I decided to deep-dive into this issue using Wireshark to determine where in the path the TLS handshake fails and if the connection is closing on the client or server-side. After rummaging through some documentation online, I discovered that `SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL` is a generic error code returned if an `SSL_read` or `SSL_write` fails in OpenSSL. After analysis with Wireshark, I found that the client never sent the ACK to the SYN-ACK sent by the server, indicating the connection was never fully established. Since I am using non-blocking sockets, I just needed to make sure the socket was finished connecting before attempting the TLS handshake.

Hopefully, this helps if someone has a similar issue.